# Mock server based on Open-API specifications

Tags: java, spring-boot, mocking

Hi I am trying to create a mock server written in Java preferibly using Spring-boot, using a given 3GPP Open-API specifications. Do you have some hints, framework to use to create a basic configuration starting from the given Open-API definition?
I know it is a general question but I am searching for advice to follow, thanks.

Comment: why not using this one? https://www.mock-server.com/mock_server/using_openapi.html